# Calling rspec methods from different file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to write a class in my code to wrap some of the RSpec calls. However, whenever I try to access rspec things, my class simply doesn't see the methods.

I have the following file defined in `spec/support/helper.rb`

```
require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'

module A
  class Helper
    def wrap_expect(dbl, func, args, ret)
      expect(dbl).to receive(func).with(args).and_return(ret)
    end
  end
end
```

I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'expect'`, despite requiring the correct module. Note that if I put calls to rspec functions before the module, everything is found correctly.

I've tried adding the following like to my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
  config.requires << 'rspec/mocks/standalone'
```

But to no avail.

I managed to use class variables in my class and passing the functions through from the global context, but that solution seems quite extreme. Also I was able to pass in the test context itself and storing it, but I'd rather not have to do that either.

Comment: Add this line `Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }` to in `spec_helper.rb`

Comment: I do have that line already, the module is being imported correctly in my test, just the rspec functions are not found in the Helper class.

Answer (score 0):

`expect` functions by default is associated with only rspec-core methods like `it` `before` . If you need to have expect inside a method, you can try adding the Rspec matcher class in the helper file.

```
include RSpec::Matchers
```

Answer (score 0):

that error because the `self` which call `expect` is not the current rspec context `RSpec::ExampleGroups`, you could check by log the `self`

```rb
module A
  class Helper
    def wrap_expect(dbl, func, args, ret)
      puts self
      expect(dbl).to receive(func).with(args).and_return(ret)
    end
  end
end

# test case
A::Helper.new.wrap_expect(...) # log self: A::Helper
```

so obviously, A::Helper does not support `expect`

now you have 2 options to build a helper: (1) a module or (2) a class which init with the current context of test cases:

(1)

```rb
module WrapHelper
 def wrap_expect(...)
   puts self # RSpec::ExampleGroups::...
   expect(...).to receive(...)...
 end
end

# test case
RSpec.describe StackOverFlow, type: :model do
  include WrapHelper
  it "...." do
    wrap_expect(...) # call directly 
  end
end
```

(2)

```rb
class WrapHelper
 def initialize(spec)
   @spec = spec 
 end
 
 def wrap_expect(...)
   puts @spec # RSpec::ExampleGroups::...
   @spec.expect(...).to @spec.receive(...)...
 end
end

# test case
RSpec.describe StackOverFlow, type: :model do
  let!(:helper) {WrapHelper.new(self)}
  
  it "...." do
    helper.wrap_expect(...)
  end
end
```